# Display:table-* and major browsers issues

Tags: html, css

I am developing the follow website:
http://di20studios.com/2012/royalpack/

All works fine in Mozilla Firefox and IE 8, but Safari, Opera and Google Chrome don't like my `display:table-*`CSS...

The `display:table-*` is at header and bottom.

[image]

What I want? Continuous background:

[image]

Can you enter the website and see this issue in action? How I can solve this?

Comment: Are you talking about top - right of banner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.hyperborea.org/journal/2010/05/webkit-displaytable-cell-problem/) out, I  believe you will find your problem is similar.

This is an unconfirmed webkit [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38527). My only suggestion would be to make sure you are using an HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

From [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/):

> What’s nice about this new DOCTYPE, especially, is that all current browsers (IE, FF, Opera, Safari) will look at it and switch the content into standards mode – even though they don’t implement HTML5. This means that you could start writing your web pages using HTML5 today and have them last for a very, very, long time.

Also, I might suggest you NOT use this method (display:table-*) unless it is the ONLY solution (which is never :P). There are many known issues with this method, one being that it is not supported in IE7.

A plausible solution would be to use [floating](http://jsfiddle.net/HQHE9/1) to achieve this. You will need to change the transparency over the images for the repeat-x to overlay properly. I edited the images so you can see a working example. As long as you MAKE sure to clear after the header-container, you shouldn't run into any issues using float. PS, this works in IE7+ :]

Comment: do the header images have to be partially transparent?

Comment: Yes.. if you can't do this, don't worry, I can play with Javascript and solve.

Comment: Worked with IE, Opera, FF, GC, Safari (PC, Mac and iPad)

Comment: Only one issue with transparent header solved with JS: http://jsfiddle.net/HbDUa/1/

Answer (score 0):

> Can you enter the website and see this issue in action?

If the question is as above, then my answer is: Yes, yes I can. I am using Google Chrome 18.0.1025.162 on Linux.

Comment: No, if my question is `Can you enter the website and see this issue in action?`, myself vote to close this question now.

Comment: I would do so myself as well, but I thought that would be a bit mean. :) But I see you edited it, so the question is a bit more clear now.